# Запись и чтение в файл с использованием fstream

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream

Нужно периодически писать в файл данные, и из другого потока считывать и обрабатывать.

Примерно так:

```
void write(std::fstream& fstr, char* bytes, std::size_t size)
{
    fstr.write(bytes, size);
    fstr.flush();

    if (fstr.fail())
    {
        std::cerr << "error" << std::endl;
        throw 1;
    }

    std::streampos p = fstr.tellp();
    std::streampos g = fstr.tellg();

    if (p == g)
        std::cout << "p == g" << std::endl;
}
void read(std::fstream& fstr, char* bytes, std::size_t size)
{
    fstr.read(bytes, size);
    if (fstr.fail())
    {
        std::cerr << "error" << std::endl;
        throw 1;
    }

    std::cout << "has been read " << fstr.gcount() << std::endl;

    std::streampos p = fstr.tellp();
    std::streampos g = fstr.tellg();

    if (p == g)
        std::cout << "p == g" << std::endl;
}

void seekp(std::fstream& fstr, int pos)
{
    fstr.seekp(pos);
    std::streampos p = fstr.tellp();
    std::streampos g = fstr.tellg();

    if (p == g)
        std::cout << "p == g" << std::endl;
}

void seekg(std::fstream& fstr, int pos)
{
    fstr.seekg(pos);
    std::streampos p = fstr.tellp();
    std::streampos g = fstr.tellg();

    if (p == g)
        std::cout << "p == g" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::fstream fstr;

    fstr.open("./file", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    {
        char bytes[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
        write(fstr, bytes, 3);
    }

    seekp(fstr, 0);

    {
        char bytes[16];
        read(fstr, bytes, 16);
    }

    seekg(fstr, fstr.end);

    {
        char bytes[] = { 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 };
        write(fstr, bytes, 3);
    }

    seekp(fstr, 0);

    {
        char bytes[16];
        read(fstr, bytes, 16);
    }

    fstr.close();
};
```

1) Не получается считать байты `fstr.fail()` возвращает `true`.  В чем может быть причина, и есть ли какая либо функция возвращающая код ошибки

2) Почему после записи, чтения, вызова `seekp()`, `seekg()`,  `fstr.tellp() == fstr.tellg()`?  В чем смысл тогда разделения указателя на указатель чтения и указатель записи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. При чтении данных в файле они иногда заканчиваются. Устанавливаются флаги ошибки **failbit** и **eofbit**. Узнать сколько же вы прочитали вы уже знаете : с помощью **gcount()**. После того, как дошли до конца файла нужно вручную обнулить флаги ошибок. Можно так :

`fstr.clear(fstr.rdstate() bitand ~(fstr.failbit bitor fstr.eofbit));`

Кода ошибок нет, но есть конкретные вопросы по ошибкам : `.good()` ,  `.bad()` , `.fail()` , `.eof()`.

2. Позиции чтения и записи разные, потому-что класс **iostream** слили из двух : **istream** и **ostream**. Очень проблематично было найти место под одну переменную для этого, так как потоки бывают очень разные. А при попытке чтения шестнадцати байтов у вас как раз и произошло изменение позиции чтения на -1. А позиция записи осталась та же.